# What is correct use of static functions in C?

Tags: c, static

I've found two ways of using static functions in C.

The first one is:

afile.h

```
static void afunc(void); // leaving this out gives errors
```

afile.c

```
void afunc(void)
{
   puts("a");
}

void callafunc(void)
{
   afunc();
}
```

main.c

```
void afunc(void)
{
   puts("b");
}

int main(void)
{
   afunc(); // prints b
   callafunc(); // prints a
}
```

The other way is:

afile.h

```
// declare nothing w.r.t. static functions
```

afile.c

```
static void afunc(void)
{
   ...
}
```

main.c

```
static void afunc(void)
{
   ...
}
```

Which of these two ways of using static functions is correct?

Comment: You shouldn't have prototypes of static functions in `.h` files. Their only scope is the compilation unit (`.c` file), so put the prototype at the top of your C file.

Comment: And you shouldn't declare identical static functions in different .c files.

Comment: I agree that the second way is used almost always. But why does the first way (seem) to work almost perfectly fine? Regarding your second comment, if the static function is local to each file, why then can't I use the same names (besided perhaps raising confusion) ?

Comment: The first way "works" because you're abusing the functionality of the include directive to include function definitions.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: The only scope of **all** declarations is the translation unit or less. `static` affects linkage, not scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Which of these two ways of using static functions is correct?

The second method is correct.

`static void afunc(void);` is a function *declaration*.  The *definition* of that function exists somewhere.  Since it is also *static*, if the function is used in this compilation, its *definition* also needs to be in this compilation of this unit.  The function has local linkage.

In the second case, both `main.c` and `afile.c` use their locally defined `afunc(void)`.

There is no need to declare to the global namespace that `afunc()` exist.  No other compilation unit needs to know about these local functions of `main.c, afile.c`

---

The first is usually incorrect.

The first case "worked" because both `main.c` and `afile.c` use and have a locally defined `afunc(void)`.

Should another file `foo.c()`, use `#include "afile.h"` and try to call `afunc()`, it would fail to find a matching local `afunc()` unless it too has a locally defined 
`afunc()`.

`"*.h"` is more to tell about the functions, objects, defines, types, etc. that `"*.c"` has for the global namespace to use.  Such things that are `static` are best in top of the `"*.c"` for its own use and not in `"*.h"`.

---

The first may be correct in narrow cases.

Example, the `"afile.h"` declares **and defines** a small helper function with the intention that whatever `"*.c"` that includes `"afile.h"` will get its own local version of `afunc()`.  By making it `static`, these local `afunc()` do not collide with a potential global `afunc()` or each other.

Answer (score 2):

The point of having header files is the following:

If several [translation units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) (i.e. "`.c` files") use the same data types, functions or variables, then the corresponding declarations must appear in every single translation unit. Although the programmer could theoretically write all of these declarations into every `.c` file directly, this would make it rather hard for the programmer to change the declarations, because they would have to be changed in every single `.c` file. Therefore, it is easier to just make one common header file for several translation units and make the individual translation units `#include` the header file using the [C preprocessor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/preprocessor).

Based on that, what you do in your first example is "correct" in the sense that it will work and it is valid C code. However, it still doesn't make sense, because you are using the same declaration for two unrelated functions.

Even if the functions have the same name and [prototype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prototype), the functions still are unrelated with each other. This is because the functions have [internal linkage](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration) (due to the keyword `static`).

It does not make sense for unrelated functions to share the same declaration in a header file.  For example, if you decide to modify the declaration of one function, how do you want to modify it in your source code? You cannot modify the header file, because then you would also be modifying the other functions with that name in all other translation units.

Therefore, it makes more sense for `static` function declarations to be stored inside the `.c` file and not inside a common header file.